# Android add extra items to spinner apart from database column

Tags: android, spinner

I am loading elements to spinner from the database table column. But I would like to add some additional elements also to this spinner. Is there a way to do this?

Rgds,
Sapan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) to add your own data, and use a [MergeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) to merge the cursor coming from the database and your matrix cursor.

Regards,
 Stéphane